# Calculate Specific Heat given initial temp, final temp and equilibrium temp

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, heat, temperature

I would appreciate if someone could enlighten me on this question.

Question:

A metallic object with a mass of 2 kg at 50ºC is placed in 10 L of water at 20ºC. When the
thermal equilibrium the temperature is 20.64 ºC What is the specific heat of the metallic object?

---

How I tried to solve it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Correct answer: 455.6 J/kg ºC

Why would it be this? Where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Using units would be a good start.

Comment: Hello, welcome, please check out [FAQ: How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/16683).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong value for the specific heat of water, because we're dealing with kilograms and joules here, and not calories and grams. It should be:

$$4184\ {\rm J\over kg\cdot\ ^{\circ}C}$$

and the minus sign goes away because the heat that is lost by the metal is gained by the water, hence $\Delta Q_\text{water} = -\Delta Q_\text{metal}$.

Thus, we have:

$$c_\text{metal} = 4184\ {\rm J\over kg\cdot\ ^{\circ}C}\times 10\ {\rm kg}\times 0.64^{\circ}{\rm C}\times {1 \over 2\ {\rm kg}}\times{1\over 29.36^{\circ}{\rm C}} = 456.02\ {\rm J\over kg\cdot\ ^{\circ}C}$$

Answer (score 1):

The principle of calorimetry states that in an isolated system such as a calorimeter, the total heat gained by the colder bodies is equal to the total heat lost by the hotter bodies. So since we are calculating heat lost by metal, you should take
$$\Delta T = \pu{50 ^\circ C} - \pu{20.64 ^\circ C}$$
What's more, the specific heat of water is $\pu{1 cal g-1 ^\circ C-1}$, so you should convert to SI units if you wish to obtain the answer in SI.

Comment: I've upvoted this because in part you have explained some of the answer but not all of it. Your expression for $\Delta T$ is not correct: you have $T_{initial} - T_{final}$. Please see my answer as an example of what constitutes a reasonable, full answer that addresses the OP's query.

Comment: @Todd you have done exactly the same calculation though. I have explained why I took $\Delta T$ as such, from the principle of calorimetry. You have done the same thing, but it is you who hasn't given any explanation for the -ve sign.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this 'principle of calorimetry' is just known as *conservation of energy* in most places of the world.